# map inclusion file for skobbler sdk

Tags: skmaps

I am trying to understand how to download offline maps from osm.
Eg jamaica.osm and use in skobbler for android. But so for i am confused. 
The only they provided was this,

```
public void downloadMapsXMLForVersion(int version) {
     String url =      SKPackageManager.getInstance().getMapsXMLPathForVersion(version);
      // … Download the xml from the URL … //
      // … When download is finished call [downloadPackages] … //
}
```

I really don't understand.

All i simply want is to download an osm map file and load it into map view.

Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Skobbler SDK uses .skm as a map format, which is an internal, proprietary format, so you can't use .osm

For download, on a device, start the demo project - go the “Map download” menu, navigate to North America -> Jamaica and proceed to download the map.
On the device you should now be able to find the downloaded package on: /Android/data/com.skobbler.sdkdemo/files/SKMaps/PreinstalledMaps/v1/20160426/package ) (you can search for .skm files to make things easier)